# Вопрос по SQL, поиск значения во второй таблице по значению из первой

Tags: sql

Имеем два запроса:

```
select zsl_id 
from smth.act where act_num='23324A'
```

здесь получаем `zsl_id (12345)`, по которому осуществляем поиск во второй таблице `(zsl_id=id)`

и второй запрос

```
select idm
from sle.zsl where id=12345
```

Помогите пожалуйста свести в единый запрос, left join не выходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объеденить 2 таблицы и вывести значение из второй, по поиску условия из первой, можно так:

```
select z.idm -- выводим нужные поля
from smth.act a -- из таблицы 1
join sle.zsl z on a.zsl_id = z.id  -- цепляем таблицу 2 по условию
where a.act_num='23324A' -- Накладываем ограничение на выборку
```

В итоге получите по поиску строку из первой таблицы, к ней бедут "подцеплена" строка из второй таблицы и выведены нужные поля.